# how to solve objectId failed for value "john" at path "_id" for model User

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am trying to learn nodejs. registering api is working in postman but when I try to hit authenticate API, I  get this error which in the terminal which says cast to `objectId failed for value "john" at path "_id" for model User`.
how to get rid of this error

[image: error while authenticating]

[image: register success api]

[image: auth node error]

this is my users.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const config = require('../config/database');


//user schema
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback) {
User.findById(id, callback);
} 

module.exports.getUserByUserName = function(username, callback) {
User.findById(username, callback);
} 

module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback) {
bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        newUser.password = hash;
        newUser.save(callback);
    })
})
} 

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassport, hash, callback) {
bcrypt.compare(candidatePassport, hash, (err, isMatch)=> {
    if (err) throw err;
        callback(null, isMatch);
});
}
```

// router/users.js

this is the authenticate api code which is fetching username and password from req body

```
router.post('/authenticate', (req,res,next) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    User.getUserByUserName(username, (err,user)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
            if(!user) {
                return res.json({success: false, msg: 'user not found'});
            }

            User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                    if(isMatch) {
                        // const token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
                        //  expiration: 604800  // 1 week
                        // });

                        const token = jwt.sign({data: user}, config.secret, {
 expiresIn: 604800
});
                        res.json({
                            success: true,
                            token: 'Bearer ' + token,
                            user: {
                                id: user._id,
                                name: user.name,
                                username: user.username,
                                email: user.email
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'wrong password'});
                    }
            })
    })
})
```

this is passport.js which is inside config folder

```
const JWTStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/database');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    let opts = {};
//  opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
// opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt");
 opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
    passport.use(new JWTStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done)=> {
        console.log(jwt_payload);
User.getUserById(jwt_payload.data._id,(err,user) => {
    if (err) {
        return done(err, false);
    }

    if(user) {
        return done(null, user);
    } else {
        return done(null, false);
    }
})
    }));
}
```

//db screenshot
[image]

Comment: please, add code, which creates user model instance

Comment: check this statement 

`user: {
                                id: user._id,
                                name: user.name,
                                username: user.username,
                                email: user.email
                            }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the wrong method getUserById here:

```
module.exports.getUserByUserName = function(username, callback) {
User.findById(username, callback);
}
```

Replace it with:

```
module.exports.getUserByUserName = function(username, callback) {
User.find({'username': username}, function(err, user) {
    if(err) return callback(err);
    return callback(null, user);
})
```

Comment: If I try to do this, then it says that User.findByUsername is not a function

Answer (score 0):

After some help of @veve, I am able to solve the error by this code

```
module.exports.getUserByUserName = function(username, callback) {
  const query = {username: username}
  User.findOne(query, callback);
}
```